# ¿Como hacer scraping a esta pagina?

Tags: php, scraping

Saludos estimados estoy intentando hacer el scraping a esta pagina https://www.osiptel.gob.pe/sistemas/sigem.html, intento obtener la respuesta en JSON con cURL desde php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8'); 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://serviciosweb.osiptel.gob.pe/SICEM/Consulta/ValidarImei');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"NROIMEI\":\"352101787447770\"}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8BZ4ttFWQglBhVHCM44P5wSsv-0tfWaQY3ldcG-pE-eRSO21CmIo5XjYKMNtSIQi2gXCpHtlAM0ArC4vGdNK78C8HlpQby9lIHuv9COeD4_GDdpWunhZLYifJIFghV7bFoo-OCLd79c9n5au8ZJXix4';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json;chartset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch); 

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Aparte del _token_, la petición se debe realizar por método POST y, seguramente, el servidor tendrá una validación para no permitir que se realicen peticiones desde una ubicación que no provenga del mismo dominio. De cualquier forma, edita tu pregunta para agregar el código con el que intentas acceder.

Comment: Que datos son los que deseas obtener del URL?

Comment: La respuesta que esta en al etiqueta label <div class="resp">
    <label>
        El IMEI/Serie no se encuentra reportado como hurtado, robado, perdido o recuperado.  
    </label>
</div>

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: el problema es que no logro que me muestre la respuesta a la consulta echa por el POST

Comment: Vas a tener que obtener primero la página del formulario para obtener el token, que está en un campo oculto, que se debe enviar como parte del formulario, no  en encabezados. Después ya podrás intentar hacer la petición, tratando de enviar los mismos encabezados (request headers) que ves en la pestaña _Network_ y, seguramente, agregar uno para simular que es un navegador (user agent). Solo queda esperar que el sistema no haga una comprobación del origen... cosa que dudo mucho.